# OOM with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm facing an OOM error whole training my tensorflow model, the structure is as follows:

> tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence initialized with GoogleNewsVector
>   2 * tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell) #forward 
>   2 * tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell) #backward
>   tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn wrapping the above layers
>   tf.layers.dense as an output layer

i tried to reduce the batch size down to as low as 64, my input data is padded to 1500, and my vocab size is 8938

The cluster i'm using is very powerful (https://wiki.calculquebec.ca/w/Helios/en) i'm using two nodes with 8 GPUs each and still getting this error:

> 2019-02-23 02:55:16.366766: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1273] OP_REQUIRES failed at reverse_op.cc:270 : Resource exhausted: OOM when 
>   allocating tensor with shape[2000,800,300] and type float on
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 by allocator GPU_1_bfc

I'm using the estimator API with MirroredStrategy and still no use, is there a way maybe to ask tensorflow to just run the training using the GPUs and keep the tensors stores on the main machine memory? Any other suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Running a particular operation (e.g. some tensor multiplication during training) using GPU requires having those tensors stored on the GPU.

You might want to use Tensorboard or something like that to see which operations require the most memory for your calculation graph. In particular, it's possible that first link between the embeddings and LSTM is the culprit and you'd need to narrow that somehow.

Comment: I doubt you can do that without actually decreasing either the embedding dim or the max sequence length. Any idea if the embedding itself can be stored outside of the GPU and only have the required values get fed to the GPU or something of that nature?